# Exporting to Excel 2016 in Sortable Date Format

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-excel, excel-2016

When exporting a query result from SQL Developer to Excel (format xlsx) the dates in my query seem to be exported as text.

I need to filter and sort this data in Excel.

After exporting Excel gives me the option to convert the dates to 20XX, but is there a way to format my dates fields in such a way that I can sort straight away?

My current date format in Preferences is DD-MON-RR

Comment: Use to_char(yourdate,’YYYY-MM-DD’) in your query?

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO That still outputs the date as Text to Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround; instead of exporting directly to XLSX, export result as a CSV. Excel is capable of opening such files and - guess what - sorting by date column works fine (I've just tested it). Then, if you want, save file as XSLX.

Yes, I know, this is impracticable, but that's the best I know right now.

Comment: Well, it works for me ... I wouldn't know why it does not for you.